# Input eventListener on Enter Key goes on loop

Tags: javascript, jquery

I tried to set eventListener for two input fields. I can press Enter on every input field and it runs ProductInsertPhp() function which save data to MySQL base. When I click on Submit button everything works perfectly. If I press Enter on any input field it works OK only on the first time. But if I run script again it make two inserts. Again - three inserts to base. Every time it is raised by 1.

I tried code with getElementById but it works only with one field.

```
<script>

//Works ok but only for one field.
//var polaText = document.getElementById("txtInput");
//polaText.addEventListener('keyup', function (e) {

var inputText = document.querySelectorAll(".inpt");
inputText = addEventListener('keyup', function (e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    var isEsc = false;
    var isEnter = false;
    if ("key" in e) {
        isEsc = (e.key === 'Escape' || e.key === 'Esc');
        isEnter = (e.key === 'Enter');
    }
    if (isEsc) {
        funct()
    }
    if (isEnter) {
        //document.getElementById("submitButton").click();
        ProductInsertPHP();
        console.log("insert");
    }
    });
</script>
```

There is no error messages on console. What can I do to set it to only one insert?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two things off in your code.

- You are not adding the eventListener to every inputText element, you are overriding the variable
- your `if()` has one `}` too much

Check the comments in this corrected solution:

```
<script>
var inputText = document.querySelectorAll(".inpt");
// add for loop to query all inputs and add eventlistener to every one of them
inputText.forEach(inp => {
    inp.addEventListener('keyup', (e) => {
        e = e || window.event;
        var isEsc = false;
        var isEnter = false;
        if ("key" in e) {
            isEsc = (e.key === 'Escape' || e.key === 'Esc');
            isEnter = (e.key === 'Enter');
        }
        if (isEsc) {
            funct()
        }
        if (isEnter) {
            //} <-- remove this 
            document.getElementById("submitButton").click();
            ProductInsertPHP();
            console.log("insert");
        }
    })
});
</script>
```